# fstab Read Only Error

Tags: samba, fstab

I'm attempting to automate the mounting a Samba share using `/etc/fstab`, and I'm not sure how to translate the bash command into the format fstab is expecting.

I'm able to successfully run the following bash command and see the files in the mounted share.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<user>,password=<password> //<samba-share-ipv4>/backup /home/eric/samba
```

In the `/etc/fstab/` file, I have the following line:

```
//<samba-share-ipv4>/backup /home/eric/samba cifs ro,username=<user>,password=<password>
```

When I try and then run `sudo mount -a`, i get the following error:

`mount: /home/eric/samba: cannot mount //<samba-share-ipv4>/backup read-only.`

However, all I need is read access. I've tried adding `ro` as an option above, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your `fstab` specification is incomplete.

There are lots of resources online, and in your local filesystem (e.g. refer to `man fstab`) explaining construction of the `fstab` entry. One of the more comprehensive *"how-to-recipes"* is [this one by Dave McKay](https://www.howtogeek.com/444814/how-to-write-an-fstab-file-on-linux/). It's the most detailed reference I've found, but I'll confess I've never read it from end-to-end.

I'll try to answer your question in a much less detailed way:

An `fstab` configuration line for a *Network Attached Storage* device is composed of 6 *fields*:

1. `fs_spec`: the block storage device or remote filesystem to be mounted
2. `fs_file`: the mount point in the local filesystem for the `fs_spec`
3. `fs_vfstype`: the type of the filesystem; e.g. ext4, smb/cifs, etc
4. `fs_mntops`: comma-separated, filesystem-dependent mount *options*
5. `fs_freq`: single-digit to control the dump(8) command; `0` for smb/cifs
6. `fs_passno`: single-digit to control fsck(8); `0` for smb/cifs

Your *current* `fstab` configuration is this:

1. `fs_spec`: `//<samba-share-ipv4>/backup`
2. `fs_file`: `/home/eric/samba`
3. `fs_vfstype`: `cifs`
4. `fs_mntops`: `ro,username=<user>,password=<password>`

I would suggest you try this:

4. `fs_mntops`: `ro,user=<user>,pass=<password>,nofail,vers=1.0`
5. `fs_freq`: `0`
6. `fs_passno`: `0`

Resulting in this:

```
//<samba-share-ipv4>/backup /home/eric/samba cifs ro,user=<user>,pass=<password>,nofail,vers=1.0 0 0
```

The one single element of `fs_mntops` that's most difficult to determine is the version: `vers=1.0` in my suggestion.  This seems to be vendor-dependent, and often *fussy*. Why? I *will guess* that it's due to *soft* standards, vendor software implementation of the `smb/cifs` protocol, and perhaps your host? `vers=1.0` is the oldest, and that *might* make it a *lowest-common-denominator*, but not necessarily. If `vers=1.0` does not work, you will need to do some research on your device. And [this brief overview](http://www.infotinks.com/correlating-versions-samba-smbcifs/) may help if the problem is obstinate. My approach is generally to use the first one that works, trying them in this order: `vers=1.0`, `vers=2.0`, `vers=3.0`.

For potentially helpful clues, you might try `dmesg`, `var/log/syslog` or `journalctl` - perhaps filtering for terms such as your smb server's hostname, IP, etc.